# How to get transaction details from PayU?

Tags: android, transactions, payu, payumoney

I am integrating PayU in my android application. Everything works fine but I want all transaction details(Like Payment Source, bank name,bank code etc) after successful/failure transaction. Right now in response I get only Transaction ID. Is there any way to get all transaction details in response?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this issue. You can get API details from

https://documentation.payubiz.in/check-status-apis/

by using this APIs you will get all transaction details.